# error in return response 'cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?' with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I read answer from other questions also but not able to solve:

I tried with following way but getting same error at the line of 
**return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,completionHandler: completionHandler)**

please help us in how you add @escaping in following method.

```
public func JSONResponseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(_ completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
    let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }


        let jsonResponseSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
        let result = jsonResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, nil)

        print("result: \(result.value)")

        switch result {
        case .success(let value):

            let json = JSON(value)
            print("JSON: \(json)")

            if let
                response = response,
                let responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value as AnyObject)
            {

                return .success(responseObject)
            } else {

                let error = Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: -6006 as! Error)

                return .failure(error as! Error)
            }
        case .failure(let error):

            let json = JSON(error)
            print("JSON: \(json)")

            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
    return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved now in following way

I set **extension DataRequest { }** instead in extension Request { }